# How are sublime commands defined?

Tags: bash, powershell, sublimetext2, sublimetext

In the [unofficial sublime documentation](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/) and many other places sublime commands are referenced. How are sublime commands created? And what is there any boilerplate for running a command in git bash or powershell for windows?

```
{ "caption": "Project: Save As", "command": "save_project_as" },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to the second part of your question, it appears as though calling subl (or whatever your symlink/shortcut/executable for sublime text is) and passing --command does what you are looking for.

```
Sublime Text build 3065

Usage: sublime_text [arguments] [files]         edit the given files
   or: sublime_text [arguments] [directories]   open the given directories

Arguments:
  --project <project>: Load the given project
  --command <command>: Run the given command
  -n or --new-window:  Open a new window
  -a or --add:         Add folders to the current window
  -w or --wait:        Wait for the files to be closed before returning
  -b or --background:  Don't activate the application
  -h or --help:        Show help (this message) and exit
  -v or --version:     Show version and exit

Filenames may be given a :line or :line:column suffix to open at a specific
lo
```